# Logstash Filter - add field with value current directory name

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I want to add two fields using the split filter plugin of Logstash. The following example will give more context to the problem, the directory structure is as follows:

```
Artist
  |
  |___Album
        |
        |__SongsList.xml
```

When I parse the XML data, I want to add the Album name and the Artist name to my index, which is the current and parent directory respectively.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "artist" => "What will I add here?"
      "album" => "What will I add here?"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research found what I was looking for. Turns out this can be done easily using the grok filter:

```
grok {
        match => ["path","%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:artist_name}/%{GREEDYDATA:album_name}/%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\.xml"]
    }
```